# Create in-browser IDE for own grammar

Tags: javascript, programming-languages, node.js, debugging, ide

We are going to use our new own programming language. We have designed grammar, json parser and everything seems to work.

Code in my language is transpiled into javascript and interpreted by node.js (server side part) and by chrome (client side part). Now I'm experimenting with [Ace editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ace_(editor)) as IDE. It has highlight and code completion features for custom grammars.

Now I'm thinking about debugging.  What possibilities I have to manage the breakpoints in attached node process and in browser and is there any chance to get variables values (for "watch variables" feature in my IDE)?

And what about callstack? Probably there is some protocol for communication with node in debug mode, but how to do it with browser for client side debugging?

Comment: I am really interested in this.  I don't have an answer but I would appreciate if you could edit your progress into your question or if you solve it answer your question.

Comment: no progress, that part of project is on hold now. I'm still interrested in this topic.

Comment: what was the purpose of this language? What did you need to do that JS could not do effectively?

Comment: Take a look: https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html (for node step and inspect); https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/ (how to debug in chrome, tutorial); https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/integrating (programmaticaly integrate with DevTools). Those might be interesting for your project.

Comment: If you find a way to do this please post an answer explaining what you did - I am really interested in how it turns out.

Answer (score 0):

Re:

> but how to do it with browser for client side debugging?

you may want to have a look at amasad's [debugjs](https://github.com/amasad/debugjs)

And also relevant, I believe, there is this short academic paper which introduces a "debuggable interpreter design pattern" in page / section 3:

http://www.bergel.eu/download/papers/Berg07d-debugger.pdf